# get value from html input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using js to fetch data from a form. I want only to get the value from  `<input type="text" name="postid">` into the `postid` variable.

Here is my code. I have added a comment where I want the value. (`var postid= ? //Here`).

```js
$('#comment_form_sub').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var form_data = $(this).serialize();
  //var postid= ? //Here
  console.log(form_data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="comment-form inline-items" method="POST" id="comment_form_sub">
  <input type="text" name="postid" id="postid" value="23">
  <input type="text" name="comment_content" id="comment_content" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Press enter to post comment">
  <input type="submit" style="display: none;" />
</form>
```

How can I get the value from the `postid` input into my variable?

Comment: Use `$("#postid").val()`

Comment: what does it matter? just take what you need from the serve-side code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are probably many ways.

You can do it by the following way by selecting the element directly by its name or id.

```
var postid = $("input[name=postid]").val() Or
var postid = $("input[id=postid]").val() Or
var postid = $('#postid').val();
```

If you want to get by this keyword then use any of the following ways.

```
var postid = $(this).children("#postid").val() Or
var postid = $(this).children("input[name=postid]").val() Or
var postid = $(this).children("input[id=postid]").val() Or
var postid = $(this).find("#postid").val() Or
var postid = $(this).find("input[name=postid]").val() Or
var postid = $(this).find("input[id=postid]").val()
```

Comment: It's better to hook up to element directly. Especially if id is already provided.

Comment: am i not hooking up to element directly?

Comment: By using on submit event.preventDefault; not working

<form class="comment-form inline-items" method="POST" onsubmit="form_submit('12')">
 <input type="text" name="postid" id="postid" value="23">
</form>

<script>
function form_submit(postid)
{
  event.preventDefault();
  var form_data = $(this).serialize();
}
</script>

Comment: @SiddhantSingh means you are unable to sumit form right?  use $(this).submit(); at the end

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, I think you just want to use `$('#postid').val()` to get the value of the postid input. So the whole line should look like this: `var postid = $('#postid').val();`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery for this.

Here's two ways of getting that value, one with jQuery (accepted answer) and the other with the standard methods [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) and [`Element.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

```js
// The jQuery way:
$('#comment_form_sub').on('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const postId = $('#postid').val();
  console.log(postId);
});

// You don't need jQuery:
document.getElementById('comment_form_sub').addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const postId = document.getElementById('postid').value;
  console.log(postId); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="comment-form inline-items" method="POST" id="comment_form_sub">
  <input type="text" name="postid" id="postid" value="23">
  <input type="text" name="comment_content" id="comment_content" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Press enter to post comment">
  <input type="submit" style="display: none;" />
</form>
```